# Unable to deploy contract on ropsten

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-contract, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Firstly
I installed geth  and it's running
I created an account and verified keystore file in the location:

```
~/Library/ethereum/testnet/keystore
```

Then I used:

```
Web3.personal.newAccount('password')
```

Its created an account and verified the location in:

```
~/Library/ethereum/testnet/keystore
```

Both of these accounts have test ethers. how should I transfer ether between them?
How should I authenticate the transfer?

Another issue I am facing in contract deployment

`truffle migrate` command throws an error
[image: migrate error]

Comment: Try to configure your truffle.js file with the ```gas``` param,which must be less than or equal to gas specified in your testnet genesis file

Comment: For transfering ethers use    ```web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})```

Comment: For authentication ie to unlock your account for transfer ethers use ```web3.personal.unlockAccount(“0xf48bbe21fb862029ef635fc778716f6b494313f4”, "password", 0);```

Comment: Test genseis file where to find that.?

Comment: How to see gas.?

Comment: {"address":"3e03c36a5b8da39b8bd453879c8d7861bd002e49","crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"96d6392ab070190cf42da7307b6f40941e1792ba55e6d495107fe9176466c700","cipherparams":{"iv":"0b48acb094a689ab4f460286821d7f7d"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"8ee6c0f7d2da9f3628bf6f01c0b4ef19cd5ab1892da94e711a0c285844cd8907"},"mac":"3b058dfb906438ed0124cc40bb62d6c535666524ff8c288b35ad7036e3400d89"},"id":"fe989878-6940-4cfb-9e35-0907453a20b8","version":3}

Comment: Add the ```gas:2000000``` field in your truffle.js file

Comment: How did you say that.?

Comment: Here you pasted your keystore file.No connection with your error.So just a solution to try out

Comment: So it's a random one.!

Comment: I just got it done..I am unable to understand that on ropsten.etherscan.io

Comment: In the genesis file we have to define a ```gasLimit``` param.It defines the maximum amount of gas expenditure allowed per block. If your contract uses more than this,it raises the above error.

Comment: Where is genesis file..?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `gasLimit:2000000` field in your truffle.js file.

It defines the maximum amount of gas expenditure allowed per block. If your contract uses more than this,it raises the above error.